# Find a police station nearest to a geopoint in android

Tags: android

How to find particular area's police station nearest to a geo point  in android

Comment: One way i know is You can do it by using GooglePlace Search Api. See this: [Google Place Search API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/)

Comment: here http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-build-a-mall-finder-app-mapview-location/ is a good example to find mall to nearest places...by refering this u may be able to find nearest polic stations.

Answer (score 3):

you'll need Google place API.

like : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=37.785835,-122.406418&rankby=distance&types=police&sensor=false&key="your google api key"

it will give you police stations from given location:

ex:

```
{

    "html_attributions": [ ],
    "next_page_token": "ClROAAAAuha4O-3EU2bv3HEZWC4uCwnBGNN1REl5DJmvwwGTXdIpLJJIoAjZCo7Oz3WhkVFPsrTokqCYMvoiBpsgkOtLhPApA39yG1x6HbCrUANTFB8SEO2_p9pOH43PRzuvBY6HrhwaFMRc_HgRPSM6DXi5PjVgBHS2L0Sg",
    "results": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.789787,
                    "lng": -122.404926
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png",
            "id": "e71eefdf4bb6f83053f77b6e912d3b0c93e70a07",
            "name": "Storefront Political Media",
            "reference": "CoQBeAAAALpR5H-3V8s-aWoozSfB7azhDcXMxYnQ1tf1KenvFN4hqw_xDkHgZqtwQu6zZIDm_Idx_6mx0RMDVwD6kG0lXguSw2uZxKUjQqZ94s3XRu1tSE4bPQFlHSdgCvYEXYf84DcG7-rkR4bTFxvkzrfOOhGAkm3nvJ1jsQWpAam8tSLEEhCQuzeLxsdfvLWVr8gwsEYkGhTQ2LqvI7BQER8ZBjK-6Vn2zKA7Ow",
            "types": [
                "police",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "250 Sutter Street, San Francisco"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.78386,
                    "lng": -122.412462
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png",
            "id": "a387ed44c75e75b602623c5c4601acde59e2e093",
            "name": "San Francisco Police Department",
            "reference": "CoQBfQAAAIHa4qugT0fvLQVpOZNnwI8rp1mNW2pwK7_-nLO10SOa9fdPGo2CPMFtehB5oKDT1EICYQIerGlcHln556HaTBKfXaL1MMmb0X_73SwClAYSTw1k0V90nbICrTYzcXt2F6jz2C9oC13-7_jVyVAWJ77Vo1i8SwIcN_OkjdLKjgEeEhBP0MaxKVM_UK5Q5nGVts-cGhSeCbb2llu_ab8rC1FMbxswyXFEwg",
            "types": [
                "local_government_office",
                "police",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "301 Eddy Street, San Francisco"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.783812,
                    "lng": -122.412728
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png",
            "id": "7a74ae30f53f5e6d64c16407c413e54e236ec50a",
            "name": "San Francisco Police Department Force; Tenderloin",
            "reference": "CpQBkAAAAPpjzuyg29pyo7P0guCGVwWSYWSGABIAFhe0XHCkA35KK-XqQRIiuqbRicNDZvkxPdmyPZEF519p-z6mjZKDB0gQcWBBnaHJSDf_n4ePrU07BrBB9P7mYLYR9T62dIto8Bm6v03ZeeyiKb5UV30ySNrs1I5vErfJWYbu0A1LLBNs757eHTKP6ELAM6dkqxKjBBIQ839EB8csU-AjakF3KN75QxoUKkJ1Vg7W8GucK5ICzfnoQ1fO9Fw",
            "types": [
                "local_government_office",
                "police",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "301 Eddy Street, San Francisco"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.783774,
                    "lng": -122.412944
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png",
            "id": "0d3efeeecf625bc4c1804081abdd3e0807630f36",
            "name": "San Francisco Police Department",
            "reference": "CoQBfQAAAPgce9xzk7LiKO44_LnwejGGkeoDLgu-OYel8yGwa3qbrGWdoP_XRMsiqnkdIPS6yXkhyAoi-ZXI2gYK3qy2eNqZRqzoH4spVJzkHoyXpZKAaw5pPqpxF90LJ8BIR7BTC8NZ6G0wWvU_ZkpRzBZ4eDGj7jsFJZ4obbHH0TorA2SsEhCxnCiVYI9-YOuTQTjv3WJwGhRIoh9UyZRqx52YQvf8r3F3yCJSKw",
            "types": [
                "local_government_office",
                "police",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "301 eddy st,san francisco,CA 94102"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.777301,
                    "lng": -122.402107
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png",
            "id": "522b34dca06a3c1a0bb424065ac5680f02749f26",
            "name": "San Francisco Sheriff's Department",
            "reference": "CoQBgAAAAIuFvo4NygDhwlemYL0aDUeEtU9_XFGOUvTtB5jS1aPoaUudJPjd_ju9leYCs8CbZeje8idACjTKaMqYSnxWFEPWbUnO1XOGS1avoapktXlT9uf-JSIkxEEsEyQswdfMP7cK0Ec69y9-UKnVkW6NwIlw9TtMGuqA4j0DasmGmiGZEhC_ZxRYvT7ZmU51W3aZQqosGhS7EXuLCHbWA-rANQeTUzKAClK7AQ",
            "types": [
                "local_government_office",
                "police",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "70 Oak Grove Street, San Francisco"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.781357,
                    "lng": -122.417997
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png",
            "id": "4acea41c3c7ae58298cc1e5b40d5608d0d0dcfd1",
            "name": "Federal Bureau of Investigation",
            "reference": "CoQBfQAAAKNFRxLamyCI4hbWr7juNyrA_ecIuD482GD-axiBBdZgKlvDF5vkJj8SGx__RSjrBinrQsZSj7Obtk8Vml7nPDidxUwT8kDvvY8kri0AFfBXrohe8iISSwohMPk-lBqszK1rD8uhStt4-uucmMNBFZoPOp4MD6oNcGemxwT6haa8EhCsT8jxTbVcWUigjQ2Lb5UnGhSs6eNiPclWCA3sPkDm9ACZZTc70g",
            "types": [
                "local_government_office",
                "police",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "450 Golden Gate Avenue, San Francisco"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.781249,
                    "lng": -122.417974
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png",
            "id": "ebe8312c803b968e8f1ff863cca4e2f934ba7872",
            "name": "US Drug Enforcement Administration",
            "reference": "CpQBgQAAAJ6diKHuzZXoj69pGt9EENv10e3nFnKA1C2KtWchDg3P1yYlRztrSTGXQSefiqsEWb5AHO6Qni_Xx9EFV8hWoPUJiuOSsDlBQhHNo6GfKAFzIUDSHWzi0Y154HTsSC8ddGl_h9AadhEJgwlQMNggK_hf5LkU-0jDrXdOee3GszGtrYyH7iVNK77eJyRTV_GjqRIQuiXnREl_U_UaYgLNT-ukwhoUSHpHatll_Jf8-ecjOsfo1SJD1IY",
            "types": [
                "police",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "450 Golden Gate Avenue, San Francisco"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.781249,
                    "lng": -122.417974
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png",
            "id": "bb7d9feda3a9287ea0e34b92916efdd53d01b8e4",
            "name": "US Marshals Services",
            "reference": "CoQBcwAAAFZxzSZ_jWYAWo4YBjIGZubm0URiy7JYoSRxrJKwxpIUDv6eT1PbW01Q499iMfBInkG64LWLcs_o2znz-i_W0NDpVJjrdPZnwm-sXG2_2WuJIGYTahn-4ULfLlKUyD6AXQ37TClQxWL1GXEEyzpggTg5TUgdi4OZab98qNK4jJ9kEhARopcjVDPfCl6Dk8UX4BCbGhR-JXlBlKofg8pnJNvn8vO_jB6_zQ",
            "types": [
                "local_government_office",
                "police",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "450 Golden Gate Avenue, San Francisco"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.781249,
                    "lng": -122.417974
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png",
            "id": "6bf8854d6ed199b63d7ed9fcea024d0c2f7e5381",
            "name": "US Alcohol Tobacco & Firearms",
            "reference": "CoQBfAAAAPMTmBey9FLuQZhrX6KwhGJFp0U7v_sTcdTX-XUq-pB0Xm7SVRaoUaUd73tszge8b6K06XC_NKjxz0amzAJPSEHAss6biv6y06WGrpRPDxhTKerAX5iNmyfDVAiYNJtwMI9xq7rOwIxzNwgIpHFaORz8MB4reAUkBo6PUc-hKgzbEhBrB9kgeclkDixH9qFQeDOSGhSyz5GT9L2tOnYDfNYX0vZP2rKSwQ",
            "types": [
                "police",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "450 Golden Gate Avenue, San Francisco"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.775381,
                    "lng": -122.40404
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png",
            "id": "894232a831a748a606dd084ed84789b38a7fd40b",
            "name": "San Francisco County Jail",
            "reference": "CoQBeAAAADtIDjI7Qs2mK2YbUJPZLGlSMHMJPIPyqF280NdN8bIcBuKofr2ue6_gTMiL5PWuFyRU63wvw8ecyhUoOS-p527Doyu0AiTEWpZNr99RG6eE3RhkSbvOvK-463RGQFxO9HPZAaMrcAX1QMaK6jGPfdJurNGW57J3bXpPRjjPjbeJEhCh_0ua8Njhntw9BTjDQNYIGhTLk95S4p8fccx72y5d3kHK82uJMA",
            "types": [
                "local_government_office",
                "police",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "425 7th Street, San Francisco"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.775296,
                    "lng": -122.403909
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png",
            "id": "4ee3bb8e8ffbebf4f06c60ed245074dae7317bb4",
            "name": "San Francisco Police Department; Field Operations",
            "rating": 4.3,
            "reference": "CpQBkAAAAPU3Ykx-3lfEWASNEq9K6G13VcxvU1Dxtp6sKgKEIDoLyCusw8lQiLK1SGZzsY94HswqjiqKTOOpMxU1d1sQi4s8Llcm7cLNyzrYg3ov-Wag-pFC3KijqOtCNjK_982GuYQd6ati-4mwCaKho3h5Ehl7R7bLAU2Y5QlCEKCV1UUBbHxgZINK0fvE2QRV57KB4BIQ-0x6jPSEx2mM4Qn7rUTobxoUrfHFnZnyBWPxOdlIBG9IIV1kKYA",
            "types": [
                "local_government_office",
                "police",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "19th St, San Francisco"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.775119,
                    "lng": -122.405597
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png",
            "id": "7c53e354a2ba6a232d546f6a0d4d7035fed2b5d2",
            "name": "CCSF-Sheriffs Department",
            "reference": "CoQBdgAAAFP-c3exZQI0mmXkAlwqFa0FiHzl4zGu-Aaxt3jbfsZEXVCMaeeYeC_RI2WQcqDDwrummRBr-JmsHi3WwOAEjb9DZLI8FAXAaK_Q8_tY-EWmsPz789s6d0jofW3kgMtMswM5DWERCaooTgfP0zHYbo9UvHA6rXnA-UwnHqL37TTIEhBRLJvAFmdVuokrhFXgJG9jGhQhoAkKVWfAe8YTUPHq8PCk7L8eiA",
            "types": [
                "local_government_office",
                "police",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "425 7th Street, San Francisco"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.775269,
                    "lng": -122.403757
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png",
            "id": "70201e2b1abd845b00a96fb16f4e7446bcc99375",
            "name": "San Francisco Police Department; Southern Station",
            "reference": "CqQBkQAAAJtzAlqPahtG6mfSBvNKYLoSV9hlduJokTfluyMmX_mGQOv9BC_WEEF3adDHjNq6DpGsIeeQP52euTDd2cG8NenJfCGM3dEgPtNscS5Y85LbGBJ3Xqbh5euWDwYX7gl6EotC8jVtuRrqzzPM3l-zIApsgj1GUCMjnDHYz1kkBRfkVgyxm5IBOYVa6n2i30w8Fw0Pw6CLxavKVeTkMbBdIHwSEKSKTQyGPCnjqiAju7zFfbkaFDV6hvizbtL1YrBDt54JfbzHvpWx",
            "types": [
                "police",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "850 Bryant Street, San Francisco"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.775269,
                    "lng": -122.403757
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png",
            "id": "4b803769b50e5870649b334d4c0f73991304b31a",
            "name": "San Francisco Police Department",
            "reference": "CoQBfgAAACsoN0pt2exPTjafsC2G-zFyONXx67Hbp4Xdxw9EvTzhpAXpDwfdaMzdFkh_FqLG3IFvo-Uw2a375fWDsqiLMQTqcppXFUDmsnvtCuPrNsm_BHu_l-Qkm0t7PdiZdTFNhvRtN4-QD1vrVow3K1DM6H759wrYFnOKOzCujCWLnVBsEhBQuHMIBwpVI9axkjQarGHXGhQNfwjLT8NI0o3T8PNUmh8N5llQtw",
            "types": [
                "police",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "850 Bryant Street, San Francisco"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.775269,
                    "lng": -122.403757
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png",
            "id": "5f072a25adc29d11a26c3420853f736f798a07a0",
            "name": "Police Commission",
            "reference": "CnRwAAAAlCrhKu-Ht6T9oG0bIiGYxnVYWyscJpBiDAoHxmPzfRxDZzrRlwvmk-VaALjIJfUYcRN4B1KpF6oAvaTJhRq2OPd_cSpE6UnxbrlWEFhIw0XxzYc1B3twF_cU78B4VXDO6CYHy_p8bOgbB06FKhWWexIQJRqT8QnE9_0Tf6AwllOUKBoU9crzscr0ydNhbD4xF_FpAYjuWjc",
            "types": [
                "police",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "850 Bryant Street, San Francisco"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.775269,
                    "lng": -122.403757
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png",
            "id": "1ae36e0afe411b1db057af726caa1b721ceacbaf",
            "name": "Police Department-Management Control",
            "reference": "CpQBggAAAOlLL4GfqBVhNG1hV7ufSmV2rv2ucfClR-XCVOWqHggBb9PT7eEjmmnjXqdjoBCy_C8xKsRhTaA9ZpPzD7PsjOZbDfgOMrCPnNL_LkG7ff0tXCtdb-9J32rjLei3R1z2DrYh29ojHHQgDKtxNHkATzamGBP_sELOl-ZiNFse38E80OSae1GIAEGk7qm2IrokIBIQsmlvwPng4fxp1mOof238ZhoUgKRD6wX3XyKWVFhyV0Jaj2liJt8",
            "types": [
                "police",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "850 Bryant Street, San Francisco"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.775269,
                    "lng": -122.403757
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png",
            "id": "a41f2aab19f8dcd16d2fa86735ae358884dc653e",
            "name": "San Francisco Police Department; Traffic Enforcment",
            "reference": "CqQBkgAAACqYHg8srBjh7Dm41OwSHWAKZcrJ947wfnat3up6L7UC_rPB2WKErlTbCrbm3E-vNo7TKfZg1eemSsk9B_KbOAb6ig-itLlbhRWUd3ddOpyAfrw3GuWVkkUdOVAGBzNEP9HgxRLNY5DKMFDdiP5QaggqDGZ8EoUNIJHwqUXxKUTr-jBw_lWWK5COMNrrscqgdl9DVIiDfRSRmDEVWe_HzdMSEGZMWvkOvBOEWT1G0hAkZPAaFHdaE3QokGiH68cCw-N1rYQCpP6w",
            "types": [
                "police",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "850 Bryant Street, San Francisco"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.775269,
                    "lng": -122.403757
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png",
            "id": "416a6d2815189e3fc6bbb9c9c1ffc2251b602d78",
            "name": "San Francisco Sheriffs Dept; Judicial Division-Bailiffs",
            "reference": "CqQBlwAAANcN9weLjjjijy0auo8lINWJ8UZI1bbSzXnocNs6VB0G742bqhM5B72jgULlPZuAS-olQwBoz3NoiCcT7nBoB0M0SK7jtkLzIZb2sj3sJzU4j9d5guqLvsGrtLT9ZcNs-AhtXFcKP5BEWERCpyN5Vxr9-fxpU8fkuentMnFsAoK_ZthpUvopoSfMTRXe4QYq55zq1yOeLm0ws1ChQff0ydcSELFQ1VpOsge0Vl9dGrpZHqIaFMqT7pAjbrCpAcelDTMBMLqDfsUs",
            "types": [
                "local_government_office",
                "police",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "850 Bryant Street, San Francisco"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.775252,
                    "lng": -122.403768
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png",
            "id": "ad648b77d7547f9f125feeb564341c6eee4528d6",
            "name": "San Francisco Police Department Records and Identifcation Bureau",
            "reference": "CqQBnwAAANVBI_eGm1aoTQgMY33tkBXl5UTXKeB1x2rQ8PKyQwP5QyNnmPC4cjtsAS42mX7prStXYAB3tqrg71uxNL0Xsq2dNNKEXmxxRPEGbiYlZUhuRpcplV2Kv_mBEwVO57BYw5hXSqktK903OuETm7GYZrnhaHd6bMUYo_2L6axYbDC2fOCcCHqkr_H4a52imRfTbPJ5T3m1YCqjycgzFRCAoq4SEPk-WQ7feqKvmDm6_NaI1noaFKVCYh6QnwjumS18px6BJhmZWTr1",
            "types": [
                "police",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "850 Bryant Street, San Francisco"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 37.775252,
                    "lng": -122.403768
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png",
            "id": "037d2ff49817265965fe9811a1420b2a25eafae4",
            "name": "Police Department-Investigations Bureau",
            "opening_hours": {
                "open_now": false
            },
            "reference": "CpQBhQAAAHDVOYEKDEqUGFfHMl_f3ootEmYyQlHQ2LJq8BGxIzV3tGxfEzIXPjVea06EfgynZdXeH-dCqG7I3ENN4We7eSlXGUdi6AWYZixQPPEdd_w0keEdGiiLmFncS86QcIkdyq4cLk3PBtSZFJsPgNKek0lcQAqnFpu_P-4shB8l8lNj9c9noybqA39QE_t0Wj3mlhIQ3Led9nm1rmgUtR2klj0tjxoU07GXuYYOB9_GV6q_I-hHvS365bc",
            "types": [
                "police",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "850 Bryant Street #400, San Francisco"
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"

}
```

Comment: Have you idea to get police station Phone number from any API, please help.

Comment: @naser can we do dynamic locations near by current location or if we search any location than near by places how we do this

Comment: have you got any way to get telephone numbers of nearby police stations?

Comment: @Reena there is no such public database available which is provide the telephone number in vicinity. so far the only way is to use google places api. but it will not gives you numbers for all the police station. some stations have uploded there details to the google. so you can get information about that police station only.

Comment: Thanks Naser for your valuable response, I already tried google places api.

Comment: Is there any api which returns the contact number of nearest police station?

Answer (score 0):

Do we need to take prior permission from police before creating app to send current location to police

Comment: It looks like more question than an answer.