# How to find nearest police station to a geo point

Tags: android, geolocation

How can you find a particular area's police station nearest to a Geo point in android? I set `types = type of place` to search `types = "police";` but no results were found. However, when I set  `types = "pharmacy";,types = "hospital";` it works properly. i have use this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/). Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279532/find-a-police-station-nearest-to-a-geopoint-in-android so duplicate. Not confident the answer there is worth anything though.

Comment: a simple reason for this problem is that there are no police stations within the specified radius. do you know there are definitely police stations within the raduis you are setting?

Comment: thanks i change the radius 2000 meter then i can see the police station.

Answer (score 0):

the project you are referring to is working just perfectly. The Only possible solution I can come up with is that 'there may be no 'POLICE STATION', within the give radius. Try increasing the radius, in the above sample;

change this:

```
double radius = 1000;
```

which come under the LoadPlaces AsyncTask.